# notifyDataSetChanged() in onProgressUpdate method for ListView to update the listView by AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my app. there is a ListView and populating data into list view throw ArrayAdapter which use ArrayList.

I want to update listview by AsyncTask into doInBackground method so I using onProgressUpdate method. Here I am doing notifyDataSetChanged on adapter.

But when compiler try to execute code `aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
then it throw error.

Code:-

```
private class StatisticsTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Long> {

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
        int count = 0;

        while(count < dummyClass.getStatisticsClassList().size()){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                onProgressUpdate(count);
                count++;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (count == dummyClass.getStatisticsClassList().size()) {
            statisticsTask.cancel(true);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        updateProgress(values[0]);
    }   
}

public void updateProgress(Integer... values) {
aListStatisticsClass.add(dummyClass.getStatisticsClassList().get(values[0]));
aAdapterStatisticsClass.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Error:-

```
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778): Process: com.example.elevateapp, PID: 1778
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6024)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:820)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:352)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:352)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.widget.AbsListView.requestLayout(AbsListView.java:1916)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.widget.AdapterView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AdapterView.java:814)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver.onChanged(AbsListView.java:6287)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.database.DataSetObservable.notifyChanged(DataSetObservable.java:37)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.widget.BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(BaseAdapter.java:50)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(ArrayAdapter.java:286)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at com.example.elevateapp.MainActivity.updateProgress(MainActivity.java:94)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at com.example.elevateapp.MainActivity$StatisticsTask.onProgressUpdate(MainActivity.java:81)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at com.example.elevateapp.MainActivity$StatisticsTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:67)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at com.example.elevateapp.MainActivity$StatisticsTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
03-04 15:33:49.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1778):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: `Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` The `Exception` is very clear...

Comment: call publishProgress(), onProgressUpda() is not yours to call :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`notifyDataSetChanged()` as well as all other UI-related methods have to be executed on the main (UI) thread.

`AsyncTask` on the other hand, creates and runs its own thread so that it removes the stress from the main and lets the application remain user responsive.

As per the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)), the `onProgressUpdate(...)` method is run on the UI thread, but you should call the `publishProgress(...)` method and you are invoking the `onProgressUpdate(...)` directly from a non-UI thread which causes your error.

To fix this, simply replace the `onProgressUpdate(count)` with `publishProgress(count)` and it will work. Cheers :D